# Creating an instance within the Class itself

Tags: java, instantiation

What's going on when the assignment statement executed at `Line 4`, does compiler ignore the `new operator` and keep the `foo` variable being null or something else happen to handle this awkward moment?

```
public class Foo {
 // creating an instance before its constructor has been invoked, suppose the "initializing"  
 // gets printed in constructor as a result of the next line, of course it will not print it
    private  Foo foo = new Foo();//Line 4

    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("initializing");
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess at what happens is....  OUT OF HEAP SPACE

Comment: I didn't realize the ordering mattered.  Have you tried this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't do anything special here. It could warn you that this won't work, but that is hard to determine.

You will get a StackOverflowError.

```
public class Foo {
    private  Foo foo = new Foo();//Line 4

    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("initializing");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

prints

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Foo.<init>(Foo.java:9)
    at Foo.<init>(Foo.java:7)
    at Foo.<init>(Foo.java:7)
    .. many deleted ...
    at Foo.<init>(Foo.java:7)
    at Foo.<init>(Foo.java:7)
```

Comment: How are you calling this as there is no main()